# Lector de PDF de UBUNTU no me permite hacer zoom

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, zoom

Tengo Ubuntu Mate y cuando abro un PDF en el programa que viene por defecto -que es Atril- éste lee el pdf pero lo muestra en un 50% de su tamaño normal (letras muy chicas), y no me permite hacerle zoom, ni con el conrol shift +, ni con las opciones que tiene de aumento en su menú (la opción aparece en gris, como si estuviera deshabilitada). Instalé otro programa llamado Evince (predeterminado del Ubuntu clásico) y tampoco me deja hacer zoom y el documento aparece al 40%. Cuando lo abro con LibreOffice si se puede, pero no me agrada abir un pdf en un "word", y no me gusta que se pueda editar. ¿Alguien sabe que pasa y cómo lo soluciono, por favor?

Comment: Lo puedes abrir con el navegador... :D

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo hice y el zoom funciona. Pero igual me parece raro que no se pueda con esos programas que se supone son especiales para eso. Bueno, gracias :)